# understanding shell redirection on non existant files

Tags: unix, shell, io-redirection

```
ls > ls.out
```

this will include ls.out in the list too. 
My understanding is:  > (shell output redirection operator is creating a file first (to take the STDOUT) if it is not already existing and then ls command is coming to play and it is including the just created ls.out file in the output. 
Is this correct? If not, can you please elaborate the workings of that command.

Similarly

```
wc temp > temp
```

Will print 0 0 0 temp inside the just created temp file.

This behavior of shell is interesting. I wonder, how it is actually working.  BTW, both are exercises in The Unix Programming Environment Book. As I mentioned the answer above, I want some expert to correct my understanding.

Comment: Interesting, maybe. Surprising, no. Your wc temp > temp example is asking wc to describe a file you haven't created yet. What else is it going to say?

Comment: @pavium - The problems is that, if `temp` already existed, and you just messed up and tried to get stats on it, you will accidentally overwrite it, and thus have no stats.

Comment: @pavium: Try these two and see the difference.
    wc temp
and
    wc temp > temp
In both case, temp should not already exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When redirecting standard output with `>`, the shell will create the file (as an empty file) if it doesn't already exist.  Further, that file is opened before the shell forks and execs the command being executed.  When you do `wc temp > temp`, the shell opens the file for writing and then forks and execs `wc`, passing on its open file handles in the process.

Answer (score 2):

Oversimplification:

`ls` is looking at the inode (directory entry) which the redirection created.

`wc` can see the inode that the redirection created, but when it looks at the contents they are empty because it (`wc`) hasn't written them yet.

Edit:

First, in both cases, the redirection (`>ls.out` or `>temp`) creates an empty file. An entry (inode) in the directory is made to point to the location of the file and contain some information about it. See the Wikipedia article on [inodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode).

Next, in the case of `ls`, all the entries in the directory, **including the one for `ls.out` which was just created**, are read and written to `stdout` (which in this case becomes the contents of `ls.out`).

Or, in the case of `wc`, it's counting the newline, word and byte counts of the recently created file called `temp` **which is empty** so it writes the zero counts into the file **after** it counts (nothing).

The contents of the files (`temp` or `ls.out`) are not written until after all the reading is done so they can't have been included.

For a **better way to compare** what `ls` and `wc` are doing, try this command (when `ls.out` is non-existent):

```
ls -l > ls.out
```

You should see that the file size for `ls.out` is zero according to the list contained inside (`cat ls.out`), but if you do `ls -l ls.out` you'll see that it's not zero. This corresponds to what you see happening with `wc`.

Comment: Some further explanation might help, Dennis.

Answer (score 0):

consider `wc -l temp > temp`

If `temp` already existed and had say 20 lines still the result of `cat temp` after executing the above command, it will be 0 temp.

I think this is because the shell creates a new empty `temp` even if `temp` existed thus overwriting the existing temp and hence when `wc` tries to count the num of lines in `temp` it gets zero.

In effect `> temp` is executed by shell first and then `wc -l temp` is executed.